# What are the most famous examples of theory rebranding?

Tags: terminology

This question was sparked by the observation that the rebranding of the field called "neural networks" into "deep learning" is quite impressive. I wonder whether there have been similar renamings in the past.

Comment: dynamical systems -> chaos theory ..... geometric measure theory -> fractal geometry  (Find a trendy name!  Sell more books and attract students!)

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Nice ones!

Comment: Look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/175833/what-recent-programmes-to-alter-highly-entrenched-mathematical-terminology-have

Answer (score 4):

I suggest *continental drift* to *plate tectonics*.

Comment: In all seriousness plate tectonics can be regarded as a theory that provides an explanation for the fact of continental drift. Without a proposed mechanism continental drift was just an isolated (and rather absurd sounding) idea.